# How to reference file from external folder so that it's still included in the installer package?

Tags: inno-setup

Here's what I'm trying to do:

`Source: {%QTDIR}/bin/QtCore4.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion;`

It doesn't unfold the QTDIR environment variable and gives me an error. It compiles and works fine if I add `external` flag, but I do need the file to be compiled into the installer package. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Just FYI: `{%xxx}` is expanded at runtime (which is why it "worked" when you used `external`), while `{#xxx}` (eg. `{#GetEnv("QTDIR")}` in your case) is expanded at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `ISPP #define`?

Example:

```
#define MYCONSTANT GetEnv("USERPROFILE")

[Files]
Source: "{#MYCONSTANT}\myfile.txt"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```

I'm linking to `UserProfile` here as an example, but you can define QTDIR there if it is set as system constant `%QTDIR%`.
Probably:

```
#define QTDIRCONSTANT GetEnv("QTDIR")

[Files]
Source: "{#QTDIRCONSTANT}\bin\QtCore4.dll"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
```